# Difference between Installing Lamp within Linux Distro Container vs Installing as Separately Containers?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am newbie with docker, i need some clarification here i am trying to explain 
lets say i have Windows Machine and docker desktop installed on it.

what will be the structure may i need to first run Some Linux Distro Container and within that container i will install LAMP Server? or i will parallel create Apache Container MySQL Container and Linux Container?

Secondly i noticed that there are some wordpress containers which is totally confusing because to run wordpress defiantly i need LAMP, then how this architecture will work?

Will it be like:

1 Linux Container and then i will install LAMP on it and install wordpress?
But incase of this what will be the purpose of wordpress container?

Or

- 1 Linux Container
- 1 Apache Container
- 1 MySQL Container
- 1 Wordpress Container

and all of them will be interlinked??

i am too confused please help me

Comment: your question is also confusing, so please restructure your questions. And as containers goes, maybe start with what is docker and how that works to better understand what it offers you. You can have minimal containers (without ubuntu) like Alpine and a docker compose file to run your services or even kubernetes if you want to go deeper on this path. But again understanding how docker works will help you on the long run.

Comment: Thanks @Edwin linux distro is not an issue, i saw many videos and articles but everyone is talking only about kernal structure and installations tutorials only. Please re-read my question i modified maybe this time you understand better what i am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you will try to have 1 container = 1 service/ 1 purpose and keep the containers very small.

That means you will have your MySQL in one container and your Apache Server on another container. They will run on container-linux based (here you can go and read about docker and its layering technique).

Coming back to your architecture, you need to put the Wordpress somewhere, where a server is - because without a server the software has no power to do anything, that means you will put it on the Apache container, eventually you will want to volume (check docker docs) to persist your statical data.

Lastly, you will want to connect this container with the MySQL container to be able to persist the important data there. You can do that with docker-compose (see docs) and start both containers from one command.

Now the cool part: this is already done for you here [bitnami/wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/wordpress/) and I am sure you can find a lot more on docker hub.

Comment: Hi @Edwin one more thing if you can help, after installing [link](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) wordpress is it possible to access my linux distro and do some changes in php.ini and htdocs.conf